# Script working on Windows, but not on Linux?

Tags: python

I am learning to program in Python and am still at the very beginning.
I wrote a 2 scripts to cut out IP-addresses from a nmap-output.

The first script cuts out the IP-addresses:

```
import re

file = open("test.txt", "r")
ips = open("ips.txt", "w+")

for line in file:
    ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
    if "filtered" in line:
        ips.write(str(ip) + "\n")
```

This code works fine on Windows and Linux, but (I hope I'm right) the for-loop gets every line as a list. That means, my IP-addresses have the format ['x.x.x.x'].
I wrote a second script to delete all the unnecessary characters ([ ' and ]):

```
ip = open("ips.txt", "r")
ip_filtered = open("ip_filtered.txt", "w")

for line in ip:
    s = line
    neu = s.translate(({ord(i): None for i in '[\']'}))
    ip_filtered.write(str(neu))
```

This script works well on Windows (I got a new file, just with IP-addresses), but on Linux I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zeichen_loeschen.py", line 6, in <module>
    neu = s.translate(({ord(i): None for i in '[\']'}))
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

What's the reason for this error?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have misaligned string ticks, maybe you mean `"[\']"` instead of `'[\']'`

Comment: I think his string ticks are fine, although `"[']"` might be easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same message when running with the python command on linux (which uses python 2.7). Try running it with the python3 command and your code should work.